# Is there any way to install latest LXqt 0.10 on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: desktop-environments, lxqt

I heard it is the most lightweight DE ever made. For my Pentium 3 desktop, I guess this well designed new LXQT would be just perfect!

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to point out is, `lxqt` is still early in development, you will face issues with this desktop and should not replace your default desktop, please see the comment by DK_bose for some details

For 16.04 the latest `lxqt` is in the default repository

```
sudo apt-get install lxqt
```

For older versions of Ubuntu, add the Lubuntu development PPA to get up to date versions.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:lubuntu-dev/lubuntu-daily && sudo apt-get update
```

Then install these packages

```
sudo apt-get install lxqt-metapackage lxqt-panel openbox
```

Now log out and you can choose `lxqt` as your desktop.

[Source](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/02/install-lxqt-0-9-ubuntu/)

Comment: LXQt for 16.04, let alone 14.04, isn't particularly recommended. Please see https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-devel/2016-May/000466.html and other related messages. I also don't know where OP got "it is the most lightweight DE ever made" from.

Comment: Good point, I understand it is early days for `lxqt` but OP asked for it and this is how to get it, I will update the answer to reflect your comment @DKBose